# Running Total of all Previous Rows BigQuery

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, sum, window-functions

I have a BigQuery Table which looks like Below:

```
ID  SessionNumber  CountOfAction   Category
 1       1              1            B
 1       2              3            A
 1       3              1            A
 1       4              4            B
 1       5              5            B
```

I am trying to get the running total of all previous rows for CountofAction where category = A. The final Output should be

```
 ID  SessionNumber  CountOfAction
 1       1              0   --no previous rows have countofAction for category = A
 1       2              0   --no previous rows have countofAction for category = A
 1       3              3   --previous row (Row 2) has countofAction = 3 for category = A
 1       4              4   --previous rows (Row 2 and 3) have countofAction = 3 and 1 for category = A
 1       5              4   --previous rows (Row 2 and 3) have countofAction = 3 and 1 for category = A
```

Below is the query I have written but it doesn't give me desired output

```
 select 
 ID,
 SessionNumber ,
 SUM(CountofAction)  OVER(Partition by clieIDntid ORDER BY SessionNumber ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED 
 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)as CumulativeCountofAction
 From TAble1 where category = 'A'
```

I would really appreciate any help on this! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ID, SessionNumber,   
  IFNULL(SUM(IF(category = 'A', CountOfAction, 0)) OVER(win), 0) AS CountOfAction
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WINDOW win AS (ORDER BY SessionNumber ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
```

If to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 ID, 1 SessionNumber, 1 CountOfAction, 'B' Category UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, 3, 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 3, 1, 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 4, 4, 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 5, 5, 'B' 
)
SELECT ID, SessionNumber,   
  IFNULL(SUM(IF(category = 'A', CountOfAction, 0)) OVER(win), 0) AS CountOfAction
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WINDOW win AS (ORDER BY SessionNumber ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
```

result is

```
Row ID  SessionNumber   CountOfAction    
1   1   1               0    
2   1   2               0    
3   1   3               3    
4   1   4               4    
5   1   5               4
```

Answer (score 2):

Filtering on `category` in the `where` clause evicts `(id, sessionNumber)` tuples where `category` `'A`' does not appear, which is not what you want.

Instead, you can use aggregation and a conditional `sum()`:

```
select
    id,
    sessionNumber,
    sum(sum(if(category = 'A', countOfAction, 0))) over(
        partition by id 
        order by sessionNumber
        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ) CumulativeCountofAction
from mytable t
group by id, sessionNumber
order by id, sessionNumber
```

Comment: Thanks for you hep but I am getting an error "Function not found: sumif"

Comment: @TigSh: I am suprised, I thought this function did exist in BQ... Fixed anyway.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Also, how will the query change if instead of CountofAction I need to do count(Category) -----Count of how many categories = A. Not Sure if I should post this as another question. Appreciate your help

Comment: @TigSh: you could do: `sum(countif(category = 'A')) over(
        partition by id 
        order by sessionNumber
        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    )  CumulativeCountofCategoryA`